# Vercel deploy / build fail. "Failed to compile. Type error: Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my first `Next.js` app using Vercel.

Even though my app runs fine on my local machine (I mean, it builds locally with `yarn run build` and I'm also developing normally when using `yarn run dev`), **my build/deploy on Vercel is failing.**

> Failed to compile
> Type error: Cannot find module '../../pages/error/ErrorPage' or its corresponding type declarations.

Here is the build logs I'm getting:

[image]

These are the related files' contents:

**app/components/async/AsyncContainer.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import ErrorPage from "../../pages/error/ErrorPage";
import NotFoundPage from "../../pages/not-found/NotFoundPage";
import SpinnerFullPage from "../spinners/SpinnerFullPage";
import { PageStatus } from "types";
import { useInitializing } from "app/hooks/stateHooks";

interface AsyncContainer {
  status: PageStatus,
}

const AsyncContainer: React.FC<AsyncContainer> = (props) => {

  const { status } = props;
  const initializing = useInitializing();
  const ERROR     = status === "ERROR";
  const LOADING   = status === "LOADING";
  const NOT_FOUND = status === "NOT_FOUND";

  return(
    LOADING || initializing ?
      <SpinnerFullPage/>
    : NOT_FOUND ?
      <NotFoundPage/>
    : ERROR ?
      <ErrorPage/>
    : <React.Fragment>
        {props.children}
      </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default AsyncContainer;
```

**app/pages/error/ErrorPage.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Image from "next/image";
import RichText from "app/components/text/RichText/RichText";
import { IMAGE_URL } from "app/constants/IMAGE";

// ... A BUNCH OF STYLED COMPONENTS LIKE:
//  const Container_DIV = styled.div``;

interface ErrorPageProps {}

const ErrorPage: React.FC<ErrorPageProps> = (props) => {
  console.log("Rendering ErrorPage...");
  return(
    <Container_DIV>
      <MaxWidth_DIV>
        <Title_H1>
          500
        </Title_H1>
        <Ratio_DIV>
          <Image_DIV>
            <Image
              layout={"fill"}
              objectFit={"cover"}
              src={IMAGE_URL.ERROR}
            />
          </Image_DIV>
        </Ratio_DIV>
      </MaxWidth_DIV>
    </Container_DIV>
  );
};

export default React.memo(ErrorPage);
```

What could possibly be happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, this was a weird bug.

This issue seems to be related: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11742#issuecomment-695810009

The cause:

- Somehow my `git config ignoreCase` was set to `true`. Even though the default is `false` and I don't remember ever changing it.
- At some point that `ErrorPage.tsx` was in a folder named `Error` with first capital letter. I decided to change it to lowercase `error`.
- I guess that because `git config ignoreCase` was set to `true`, basically git treated as being the very same path.
- Somehow this was ok on my Windows local environment, but not ok on Vercel remote build platform.

I know that becase once I've set `git config ignoreCase` to `true`, I began getting a different error. Something like this:

> Type error: Already included file name '/vercel/path0/app/pages/error/ErrorPage.tsx' differs from file name '/vercel/path0/app/pages/Error/ErrorPage.tsx' only in casing.

So I've renamed the folder to `error-aux/ErrorPage` and now it's building successfully.

Reference:

- https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add --all .
git commit -a -m "Versioning untracked files"
git push
```

this works for me