# Changing the file name causes an error when deploying Vercel

Tags: next.js

When I change the file name, you will get an error when deploying Vercel.
I was affected by the

```
components/NavBar.tsx
```

and

```
pages/ThankYou.tsx
```

files.

After initially deploying with the above names, I had aligned all the filenames in lowercase, so I had to rename

```
components/navbar.tsx
```

and

```
pages/thankyou.tsx
```

and deployed them.

I got an error like the following image and the deployment failed.
[image]

text version:

```
21:59:05.755    https://nextjs.org/telemetry
21:59:05.809    info  - Checking validity of types...
21:59:13.352    Failed to compile.
21:59:13.353    ./pages/about-iq.tsx:7:20
21:59:13.353    Type error: Cannot find module '../components/navbar' or its corresponding type declarations.
21:59:13.353       5 | import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
21:59:13.353       6 | 
21:59:13.353    >  7 | import NavBar from '../components/navbar';
21:59:13.353         |                    ^
21:59:13.353       8 | import Footer from '../components/footer';
```

thankyou.tsx is a page, so there is no error at this point, but when I renamed it back to `NavBar.tsx` again and deployed it, and accessed the `domain/thankyou`, I got a 404 error.
At this point, when I accessed the `domain/ThankYou`, I was able to access it.

I thought it was caused by vercel's cache function and tried Redeploy, but it didn't help.
I also tried deleting node_modules, .next, and package-lock.json, but to no avail.

If you know of any strategies, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

PS:
Thank you for your answering!
Does this mean that it is detecting the change?
[image]

Comment: How are you deploying to Vercel? If you are using the git integration, can you verify if your changes are present in your repository? I am asking this 'cause by default git ignores the file case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vercel deploy / build fail. "Failed to compile. Type error: Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420394/vercel-deploy-build-fail-failed-to-compile-type-error-cannot-find-module)

Comment: Perfectly done!
And the error message after I fixed it was the same!
I have a log of the fix on github, but I still can't get there.

I renamed the directory, pushed it, and then pushed it back again, and it came back fine.
I put the pages directory in the src directory and fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

[Vercel deploy / build fail. "Failed to compile. Type error: Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420394/vercel-deploy-build-fail-failed-to-compile-type-error-cannot-find-module)

I was able to perfect it with this question that Mr. A put up.

And the error message after I fixed it was the same!
I have a log of the fix on github, but I still can't get there.

I renamed the directory, pushed it, and then pushed it back again, and it came back fine.
I put the pages directory in the src directory and fixed it.

Comment: To summarize the solution in that post: Run `git config core.ignorecase` to check if git is ignoring case changes.  Run `git config core.ignorecase false` to observe case changes in the current repo. Run `git config --global core.ignorecase false` to case changes in every repo.

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick fix, you can update the reference of the file by removing it and it will be seen as a new file during the build.