# Type error: cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, deployment, vercel

I've been trying to deploy my next.js app on Vercel, but got "Type error: cannot find module '...' or its corresponding type declarations" error. My guess is it happened with local module(React Component) and .tsx and .ts files. Because I didn't get this error when I deployed the last version without typescript.

In development mode the app able to find the modules and execute the code effectively without any error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I'm too late. I hope this help :)

[Vercel deploy / build fail. "Failed to compile. Type error: Cannot find module ... or its corresponding type declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420394/vercel-deploy-build-fail-failed-to-compile-type-error-cannot-find-module?rq=1)

or you can look at this issue
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11742

Comment: Please do not post link only answers try to explain more

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33741104)